# How to format x and y labels in seaborn.heatmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following pivot table

```
    y          -0.999418  -0.996936  -0.992476  ...   0.992476   0.996936   0.999418
    x                                           ...                                 
    -0.999418  -0.138748  -0.138468  -0.137962  ...   0.133162   0.133567   0.133791
    -0.996936  -0.139005  -0.138725  -0.138218  ...   0.133328   0.133733   0.133957
    -0.992476  -0.139466  -0.139184  -0.138678  ...   0.133627   0.134032   0.134257
    -0.986046  -0.140125  -0.139843  -0.139336  ...   0.134056   0.134464   0.134689
    -0.977657  -0.140978  -0.140696  -0.140187  ...   0.134618   0.135026   0.135253
    ...              ...        ...        ...  ...        ...        ...        ...
     0.977657  -0.128956  -0.128744  -0.128362  ...   0.137515   0.138024   0.138307
     0.986046  -0.128371  -0.128160  -0.127780  ...   0.136634   0.137143   0.137425
     0.992476  -0.127922  -0.127712  -0.127334  ...   0.135954   0.136461   0.136743
     0.996936  -0.127611  -0.127402  -0.127024  ...   0.135479   0.135986   0.136267
     0.999418  -0.127438  -0.127229  -0.126852  ...   0.135214   0.135721   0.136002
    
    [70 rows x 70 columns]
```

Both x and y are numbers ranging from the -1 to 1. I want to plot the values of x and y using `seaborn.heatmap`. When I run the following code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(pivot_table, ax = ax)
plt.show()
```

The tick formatting on the x and y axes looks like this

[image]

This is not visually pleasing, so I want to display the first 3 decimal numbers of each tick only. I have tried to do so using the following approaches

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.3f"))
```

and

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '%.3f' % x))
```

But both options result in the following tick formatting

[image]

The values that are displayed are formatted to show 3 decimals only, but the values no longer represent the actual values of x and y.

**Question:** How do I format the x and y values when plotting the pivot table so that they are rounded on 3 decimals? (I do not want to round the actual values in the pivot table)

Comment: you could try this. but I have not testet it...
ax.set_xticklabels(["{:.3f}".format(x) for x in ax.get_xticks()])

Comment: An easier way could be to round the numbers at the time of creating the pivot table. Or just round the column names and the index.

Comment: `set_major_formatter` does not work here, because the ticks are not numerical, they are strings.  To change these categorical ticks, you need `ax.set_xticklabels(...)`  as suggested in the first comment.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, unfortunately the solution doesn't work; I get the same result as with the two approaches that I showed in my original question.